get_original_cwd() function in hydora-core requests initialize in spite of I think I have initialized
get_original_cwd() function in hydra requests initialize in spite of I think my code had initialized.
Minimum code showing my error:
import os

import hydra
from hydra.core.utils import setup_globals
from hydra.utils import get_original_cwd
from omegaconf import OmegaConf

with hydra.initialize(config_path="conf", version_base=None):
    cfg = hydra.compose(config_name="try_config")
print(OmegaConf.to_yaml(cfg))
# reinitialize hydra
setup_globals()
output_dir = get_original_cwd()  # ValueError: get_original_cwd() must only be used after HydraConfig is initialized
os.makedirs(output_dir, exist_ok=True)
with open(os.path.join(output_dir, "result.txt"), "w") as f:
    f.write("Test")

Error:
ValueError: get_original_cwd() must only be used after HydraConfig is initialized
try_config.yaml:
a: 1
b: 2
hydra:
  run:
    dir: "outputs"


Similar::::
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78166700/i-get-valueerror-hydraconfig-was-not-set-when-i-use-hydra-initialize

Solved. get_original_cwd() works only under the decorator @hydra.main(). That may be specification of their design.

I changed my code to the below. I want to write my code by class structure. The code satisfied my requests and hydra design(specification),perhaps.
import hydra
from omegaconf import DictConfig

@hydra.main(config_path="conf",config_name="config")
def under_hydra(cfg:DictConfig):
   Test(cfg_para=cfg,hydra_cfg=HydraConfig().get())

